# Login successful with wrong credentials swagger, nodeJS, JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, swagger

Created a login method but it spits out the token regardless of what is entered in the Userfields
This uses swagger API and I'm trying to develop the frontend and backend

I'm relatively new to nodejs/javascript
Any Help would be appreciated!

login.js

```js
var form = document.getElementById('login')
form.addEventListener('submit', login)

async function login(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value

  const result = await fetch('/v1/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username,
      password
    })
  }).then((res) => res.json())

  if (result.status === 'ok') {
    // everythign went fine
    console.log('Got the token: ', result.data)
    localStorage.setItem('token', result.data)
    alert('Login Successful')
    return false;
  } else {
    alert(result.error)

  }
}
```

userController.JS

```js
 login: async (req,res)=> {
        
            const { userName, password } = req.body
            const existUsername = await userModel.findOne({ userName: req.body.userName, password: req.body.password}).then((existUsername) =>{
                if (existUsername){
                    res.status(400).json({status: 'Failed', message: `User was Not found`, data: null})
                    return;
                }
            try{
                async() => { 
                    await bcrypt.compare(password, req.body.password) }
            // the username, password combination is successful
            const token = jwt.sign(
                {
                    id: userModel._id,
                    userName: userModel.userName
                },
                JWT_SECRET
            )
            
            
           res.json({ status: 'ok', data: token })
            
        }
        catch (e) {
            res.status(400).json({status: 'Failed', message: `${e.message}`, data: null})
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: res.json, i.e when you resond should be in async() => { else it happens before

Comment: also dont store tokens in localstorage

Comment: You have `if (existUsername) { res.status(400)...` I don't think that's what you want. Also your bcrypt code does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Also note that if you need bcrypt to compare the password, then putting req.body.password in the query will always fail, and since your if logic is backwards, every login attempt succeeds.

Comment: so the response needs to be moved within the async function? Or needs it's own "await"? Sorry I'm pretty new!

Comment: You need to 1. find User based on username, failed 400 if not found 2. compare the user's password and the submitted one using bcrypt, failed 400 if no match 3. create token, 200 ok